# Start process using wildcard for drive letter

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a file which will always be located on a users desktop, however, depending on how the machine was set up, the desktop could be located on the C drive or D drive.

Below is what I have tried to use.  On it's own, `(Get-Location).Drive.Name` will return the C drive on my machine.  However, if I combine it into the full line of code to start the program, it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$userName = [Environment]::UserName
Start-Process ((Get-Location).Drive.Name)\Users\$($userName)\Desktop\VIPHorizon\Service_Desk.url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other answer is correct that you are missing a colon, simply adding that is not sufficient.

If you try running it with the colon, you will get another error like so:

`Unexpected token ':\Users' in expression or statement.`

In order to fix this, you need to wrap the whole thing in quote marks.

`"((get-location).Drive.Name):\Users\$($userName)\Desktop\VIPHorizon\Service_Desk.url"`

Then you will find that the `((get-location).Drive.Name)` is written directly into the string, instead of being replaced. which can be fixed by prefixing the call with a dollar sign like you have already done for userName.

`"$((get-location).Drive.Name):\Users\$($userName)\Desktop\VIPHorizon\Service_Desk.url"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a colon ( : ) right after your drive letter:

```
$userName = [Environment]::UserName
Start-Process ((get-location).Drive.Name):\Users\$($userName)\Desktop\VIPHorizon\Service_Desk.url
```

Comment: Ah, I thought that would work!  However, it still doesn't.  I tried it with a random txt file just to make sure it wasn't something with the .url file.  I must be missing something else.

Comment: What do you see if you use replace Start-Process with Write-Host? Is the path correct?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to get current users Desktop even if relocated is:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
```

So use:

```
Start-Process (Join-Path [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') "VIPHorizon\Service_Desk.url")
```

To eumerate all special folders and current settings:

```
$SpecialFolders = [Environment+SpecialFolder]::GetNames([Environment+SpecialFolder])|Sort
ForEach ($SpecialFolder in $SpecialFolders) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SpecialFolderName = $SpecialFolder
        SpecialFolderLocation = ([Environment]::GetFolderPath($SpecialFolder))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The global Powershell variable `$HOME` will give you the home location for the active user.

```
Start-Process $HOME\Desktop\VIPHorizon\Service_Desk.url
```